# Connecting to Availability Group Listener using JDBC getting error

Tags: sql-server, availability-group

I am getting the below error when my application tries to connect using AG Listener thru JDBC. `Multisubnetfailover=true` has been added to the connection string, but it is still not working.

> TCP/IP connection to the host , port 1433 has failed. Error: "Listener": Name or service not known. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port.

When the application is trying to connect using the IP on port 1433, it is working.

Here is the connection string:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://Listener:1433;databaseName=test;MultiSubnetFailover=true
```

Comment: It's hard to tell, because your connection string isn't shown in the question, but it seems like you have `instanceName=Listener;` in it. Is that the correct instance name?

Comment: Sorry I just added a random AG Listener. For the instance name, i used the AG listener name with FQDN.

Comment: If it connects when using IP address but not when using a host name, either: 1) the host name is incorrect, 2) the DNS isn't resolving it, or 3) the client computer's DNS settings are using incorrect DNS server/s.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask the client. 

When I tried connecting to Listener using ODBC data source admin, it works fine when enabling the Multisubnet failover.